# Can I recover from a complete OS X hard drive crash using CrashPlan Central?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, backup, restore, crashplan

The CrashPlan web site states:

> Once your files are backed up,
>   CrashPlan continuously checks that
>   your files are 100% healthy and ready
>   to restore when you need them. If it
>   finds any problems, CrashPlan fixes
>   them.

Does this mean if my hard drive completely crashes, it can restore the OS, system files, and personal files? Specifically, can ***CrashPlan Central*** do an entire clone-type restore on Leopard?

Thanks, Chirag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CrashPlan is designed to protect your data, not your system.  That being said, on the mac-- select "/" and once its' backed up .. do a  full restore to a freshly formatted drive.

Then "bless" the drive.  You should boot fine.

~Matthew

Comment: +1 for data, not system. I suspect that even if you backup "/" you will still miss important stuff like boot loaders and MBR, so it probably won't work.

Comment: "Bless" is the command to fix the bootloader and MBR on Mac OS. From the man page: *bless -- set volume bootability and startup disk options*

Comment: How about on Windows?  I'm assuming not as easy/simple...